# print at least one decimal place in c++?

Tags: c++, double, cout

I want to stringify `double` values in C++ with up to 10 decimal places, so I use something like

```
std::stringstream s;
double value = 3.1415926;
s << "value is " << std::setprecision(10) << value;
```

However, if `value` has some exact integral value such as 4.0, I want it to print `4.0` and not just `4`.   Is there some way to accomplish this with either C++ `stringstream`, or even old-school `snprintf()`?

So far, the only solution I can think of is to compare `value` to `floor(value)`:

```
std::stringstream s;
if (floor(value) == value)
  s << std::setprecision(1) << std::fixed << value;
else
  s << std::setprecision(10) << value;
```

I'll keep that solution if I have to, but I'm curious if I'm overlooking some iostream gadget that could help me avoid the conditional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed):

```
s << "value is " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(10) << value;
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/1WwPYM)

---

**Update**: I think I misread what you are looking for. `std::fixed` alone doesn't address the issue you are looking to solve - using precision 1 for whole numbers and precision 10 for fractional numbers.  You can use [`std::modf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf) to differentiate between them (for simplicity, I'll ignore Infinite and NaN, but make sure you account for them in your actual code), eg:

```
#include <cmath>
std::stringstream s;
double integral;
if (std::modf(value, &integral) == 0)
    s << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << integral;
else
    s << std::fixed << std::setprecision(10) << value;
```

Comment: I was confused by your answer, because I already use `std::fixed` in my own conditional solution.  But regardless, I just checked your "Live Demo", and it is not generating the desired output;  it needs to output `4.0` (for the special case of exact integral values), not `4.0000000000`

Comment: @RyanV.Bissell then you answered your own question. You have to set the precision conditionally.